# Can anyone help me with Azure's account-management service name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-organizations

I wanted to know the Azure service which is same as AWS service known as **AWS Organizations** where we can create sub-accounts with subsequent roles, which can be accessed using the **SWITCH ROLE** functionality in AWS.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 answers to this.

1. There is no such a service
2. Azure is using tenants and subscriptions for logical grouping. You can switch between tenants, but you cannot unite them. However, if you use subscriptions inside tenants you can use tenant as the central object to control everything under this same tenant.